# I am looking for online inplace editor

Tags: jquery

Any online inplace editor recommend? I need some jquery plugin that can inplace edit my `<p>` tags. Currently I am using a library called inlineEdit.js> It works fine for just editing. But I don't like the way that it needs to click to save. I want it like I leave the box and it save. Also, I would like it have bar that I can create a link and change font. I also tried some rich editor, the one I like is elRTE. But I don't like the way that it is not adding the text in my `<p>` tags. Do any one has a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/), I've had great successes with it and it's been extensible and lightweight enough for my purposes.

Comment: I want to get some opensource one

Comment: When you pay for Redactor you get its source. So you can hack away at it. It's also designed in such a way you can add custom buttons or functions with relative ease.